# How to use ng-repeat without specific name in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing website with AngularJS.

I grabbed the json data from the server. and I need to display it on the table.

Json data format is

```
  { 
    {"a" :1,"b": 2,"c":3}, 
    {"a" :3,"b": 4,"c":5}, 
    {"a" :1,"b": 2,"c":3}
  }
```

The problem is each bracket's names; a, b,c are the dynamic data from the server so that the server guy can change the name.

There is my psedocode

```
    <tr ng-repeat = "jsonObj in jsonArray"> 
     <td ng-repeat = "name in jsonObj">{{name}} </td>
  </tr>
```

it doesn't work.  I think I know what it doesn't work.  but I cant think of how to change
without knowing the name of json array.
Since a, b,c are dynamic, i can't just type `{{jsonObj.a}}  {{jsonObj.b}}`

I hope anyone can help me to fix this. 
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use the following format:

```
ng-repeat="(key,value) in myObj"
```

This means you can quite easily display the value and key separetly by just doing `{{key}}` or `{{value}}`

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in jsonArray">
  <td ng-repeat="(key,val) in obj ">{{val}}</td>
</tr>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat for more details on the different forms ng-repeat can take

Comment: I tried that. I tried <tr ng-reapt="(key,value) in jsonArray"> {{value}} </tr>.. doesn't work

Comment: Is datasource an array or an object?

Comment: this isn't right, OP wants to repeat the `<td>`'s using `(key,value)`

Comment: combined..  it is the array of object.something like this { 
    {"a" :1,"b": 2,"c":3}, 
    {"a" :3,"b": 4,"c":5}, 
    {"a" :1,"b": 2,"c":3}
  }

Comment: @user1979727  outer braces should be `[]` in your data or is invalid. Need to use the same repeat you already have on the `<tr>` then use `<td>` repeats in answer

Comment: Doesn't each entry in your object need a valid key?

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, made the appropriate edits

Comment: Thank you Thank you guys. I fixed it  <tr ng-repeat = "jsonOb in jsonArray"> <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in jsonOb">{{v}}</td></tr> Because tr should contains array and td should take object.  Now I know how to use it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is you want rows and cells based on json data.

This is very simple but you may just need an array like.

```
 $scope.items =  [ 
  {a:1,b: 2,c:3}, 
  {a:3,b: 4,c:5}, 
  {a:1,b: 2,c:3}
];
```

and not an object.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/8ykLm/)